# Why does the blowup of a curve at a singular point decreases the arithmetic genus?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity, blowup

In Beauville's *Complex Algebraic Surfaces*, problem II.20 we are asked to show that an irreducible curve $C$ in a smooth surface $S$ becomes smooth after a finite number of blowups. He says that a way to do this is to show that the arithmetic genus decreases everytime we blowup $C$ at a singular point.

There is a proof of this in Barth, Hulek, Peters, Van de Ven's *Compact Complex Surfaces* using the following idea (I'll paraphrase):

Consider the case when $C$ has only one singular point $P$. Let $x,y$ be local coordinates for $S$ in a neighbourhood $U$ of $P$, so that the blowup is described as the subvariety of $U\times\Bbb{P}^1$ given by $sy=tx$.

We will assume that $y=0$ is the only tangent direction of $C$ at $P$ and that the multiplicity of $\widetilde{C}$ at the corresponding point is the same (in the other cases, the multiplicity clearly decreases). Then $C$ is described locally by the power series
$$f=ay^m+\sum_{i+i> m}a_{ij}x^iy^j.$$

Restricting to the open set $V_s=\{s\neq 0\}$ and writing $t$ instead of $\frac{t}{s}$ for simplicity, we get that the strict transform $\widetilde{C}$ is given by
$$\widetilde{f}=at^m+\sum_{i+j>m}a_{ij}x^{i+j-m}t^j$$

Then we observe that the order with which $\widetilde{f}(x,0)$ vanishes at the origin is strictly less than the order with which $f(x,0)$ does, which shows that the process will eventually terminate.

I understand all that, but I still can't see how this relates to the arithmetic genus $p_a=h^1(C,\mathcal{O}_C)$

Answer (score 0):

For those like me who are interested, this is in fact given in Hartshorne with corollary 3.7 (arithmetic genus decreases) and proposition 3.8 (finite number of blowups) in chapter V on surfaces.

The idea is that since the arithmetic genus decreases every time we blow-up at a singular point of a curve, if we have an infinite sequence of blow-ups which have a singular point, we would get that at some point the arithmetic genus is negative which is absurd. Thus at some step the strict transform by the blow-ups of $C$ is smooth.

However I don't know if we implicitly use the arithmetic genus in your proof.